# Conversion failed in MERGE TABLES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two `TABLES`

1. `SOURCE_TABLE`
2. `TARGET_TABLE`

I want to update the old records and insert new records in `TARGET_TABLE` from `SOURCE_TABLE`, and I used `MERGE` for this operation.

Notice: I have a date value with `nvarchar` datatype in `SOURCE_TABLE` and I have date value with `datatime2` datatype in `TARGET_TABLE`.

Now how can I fix this error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SOURCE_TABLE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Family] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreationDate] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Family] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime2] NOT NULL
)

MERGE TARGET_TABLE AS target 
USING SOURCE_TABLE AS source ON (target.ID = source.ID)

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ([Name], [Family], [Priority], [CreationDate]) 
   VALUES (source.Name, source.Family, source.Priority, 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, source.CreationDate, 101))

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET target.Name = source.Name
              target.Family = source.Family 
              target.Priority = source.Priority
              target.CreationDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, source.CreationDate, 101)
```

Comment: You have not supplied a data sample. The error message states that you have string data that cannot be converted because it is not in the proper format. Select from the source table with [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) and see which ones cannot be converted. Then either fix the source table, the style you use to convert, or tweak the statement to allow for differing source formats.

Comment: I used TRY_CONVERT , CreationDate column value is null

Comment: Which means the style you use to convert with is either the wrong style, or the data is not in the format you expect. Use that information to dig into the problem further.

Comment: you right ! this is my value in CreationDate field  
value===>'22-DEC-18 04.07.24.000000000 PM'
format ===> dd-month-yy hh.mm.ss
when I check this value with ISdate() the result is 0

Comment: You're using `DATETIME2` in your target table - so then **why** are you converting to `DATETIME` in your code?? Use `CONVERT(DATETIME2, ....` there too !!

Comment: @JavadAbedi That is not a style I'm familiar with, and looking at the styles in the [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) documentation I'm not seeing it there either. You will have to do some string-fiddling to get it to a `DATETIME2` column. Or have the process that creates the data export with in an ISO format, which is probably the better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing a date/time as a string?  That is the wrong format.

You can use `try_convert()` for the conversion:

```
VALUES (source.Name, source.Family, source.Priority, 
        TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, source.CreationDate, 101)
       )
```

However, that will return `NULL` when they don't match.

You might also find that leaving out the format give you better luck:

```
VALUES (source.Name, source.Family, source.Priority, 
        TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, source.CreationDate)
       )
```

SQL Server is pretty sophisticated in converting strings to date/times.

More importantly, you should find the data that fails and fix the data -- preferably by changing the column to the correct type:

```
select s.*
from source_table s
where try_convert(datetime, s.CreationDate, 101) is null and
      s.CreationDate is not null;
```

Answer (score -1):

--First i need to know why you are defining date column as nvarchar?

Just converting the column datas to datatime2 you wont get the error.

--FOR INSTANCE:

```
  select convert(datetime2,convert(nvarchar(250),getdate()))

  select convert(datetime2,getdate())
```

--ON YOUR CODE JUST REPLACE AS BELOW

```
  convert(datetime2,source.CreationDate)
```

HOPE THIS HELPS

Comment: that table filled from csv file with bulk insert and when I defining date column as datetime2 then this error will show type mismatch so I have to define date column as nvarchar and after that convert in merge. 
but now even with your code , I get error Conversion failed

Comment: i hope your input data are not valid for date format .just use the below code to check the invalid date.
   select isdate(getdate())---at getdate() replace the column name from source table